# JavaFX: Minimize/Maximize Button Animation for Undecorated Stage with GluonFX and GraalVM

Tags: java, windows, javafx, graalvm, gluonfx

I'm building my JavaFX desktop application and recently I've encountered a problem: there are no animations for minimizing/maximizing window when you use undecorated/transparent stage. I would like my application to smoothly animate on Windows machine instead of rapidly pop in/out. I've been looking for solutions on the internet but non worked for me because:

1. The solution is too old and cannot be easily applied to Java17 and JavaFX17;
2. The solution uses classes and methods that are internal and not accessible;
3. The solution uses JNA which is not supported by GraalVM native-image;
4. The "solution" doesn't work at all.

At the moment I have undecorated stage and my own minimize button. With the current implementation my app just rapidly pops in/out when minimizing window which looks quite strange.

```
<Button fx:id="MinimizeButton" translateX="340" translateY="-205"
    opacity="0" style="-fx-background-color: transparent; -fx-padding: 0"
    onAction="#MinimizeApp">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView fitHeight="40.0" fitWidth="40.0"
            pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="@MinimizeButton.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

```
@FXML private Button MinimizeButton;
@FXML private void MinimizeApp() {
    stage.setIconified(true);
}
```

And again, using JNA is not a solution, because it is not supported by GraalVM. Even if I try to build the project, it just gives me the following error if I try to tun it:

```
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB] JNA: Problems loading core IDs: java.nio.Buffer
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unsupported JNI version 0x0, required by C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-2562260\jna619958766142062904.dll
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNILibraryInitializer.checkSupportedJNIVersion(JNILibraryInitializer.java:77)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNILibraryInitializer.callOnLoadFunction(JNILibraryInitializer.java:70)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNILibraryInitializer.initialize(JNILibraryInitializer.java:126)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.addLibrary(NativeLibrarySupport.java:186)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibrary0(NativeLibrarySupport.java:142)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryAbsolute(NativeLibrarySupport.java:101)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:54)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1045)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:1015)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:221)
[яЄ ш■ы. 15 16:14:49 MSK 2022][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.<clinit>(User32.java:49)
```

I understand that those minimize/maximize animations are implemented within the Windows system itself and cannot be implemented by pure Java and JavaFX code. So the solutions I see:

1. Use JNI somehow;
2. Somehow keep the native buttons and their functionality but have the ability to modify the rest of the title bar. Something like Microsoft Edge or Windows 11 Media Player.

I hope for some guidelines on these. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know what you are referring to regarding JNA/JNI so solutions.  JavaFX has a built-in [animation framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/animation.htm), you can use that if you wish.

Comment: Usually there is an animation when you click minimize button. Your window becomes smaller and moves to the icon on the taskbar. This is a usual behavior of minimize button in the decorated stage. However if you use undecorated stage with your own minimize button with `setIconified()` the window just disappears from the screen without any animation. And I don't think it's possible to make such animation with JavaFX, at least because you can't tell exact location of the icon on the taskbar.
If you still don't understand me, I will try to make a video showing everything.

Comment: If you want the default iconicification behavior of the windowing toolkit for using a decorated window, then use a decorated window.  If you choose to have an undecorated window, that means that you have chosen to forego many of the default behaviors.  Either accept the basic uncustomized behavior or write your own custom behavior using the JavaFX animation framework, knowing that it will likely be different than the OS behavior for decorated windows.  Just my opinion.

Comment: Well, maybe. But you know there are lots of programs and apps with customized/undecorated window that still have this default Windows behavior (IntelliJ IDEA, for example). Also some people were able to make it before with JNA, so I thought that it can be also possible to do with JNI

Comment: You could implement your _own_ animations, but I doubt you can copy the default animations exactly. If you're looking to customize the title bar, I know at least some versions of Windows [support this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=wasdk#interactive-content). But JavaFX does not provide an API for this. Though if JNA, which is a wrapper around JNI, could do this, then I see no reason why this could not be done with JNI. It may involve "breaking into" internals of JavaFX though. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this.